# Structural directive to add additional div

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying add a button in addition to the element's template. Where can I define the template of the additional element which needs to be added?

```
this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
```

The above code lets me add only `TemplateRef`. Where to define the `<template>` and how to get the reference `TemplateRef` of it?

I tried doing `this.el.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div>One</div>')`. This adds the element but the added html is not Angular compiled.

Comment: There is no public API to create a `TemplateRef`. You can create a component that contains this button and add the component instead with `this.view.createComponent()` (not checked if `this.view` actually provides `createComponent()` but I assume so.

Comment: added html is not angular compiled????

Comment: Here is a good example of what @GünterZöchbauer suggest: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944487/adding-a-component-to-a-templateref-using-a-structural-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944487/adding-a-component-to-a-templateref-using-a-structural-directive)